# Azure Storage Account crossing IOPS limit

Tags: performance, azure-storage

I have Azure Storage Account and it's crossing 20K IOPS limit. How can I reduce the IOPS of the storage account? 
We are doing copy operation and also delete operation on the file share. Can we do this using batch operation so that it could be counted as one transaction.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If all the IOs are on File Share then, you are also constrained by the SMB behavior and the nature of the Fileshare contents and if are you deleting many small files? Here basically you must be deleting + creating 20,000 files every second?

Batch operations can be used only when you can delete the whole share

e.g. if you are uploading a blob, then using put blob will help reduce the IOs, instead of multiple put blocks/pages etc

You can use the following steps to measure the share IOPS from Performance Monitor. This can also be used to isolate which share has a significant amount of activity:

1. Open Performance Monitor (PerfMon.msc).
2. Go to Performance | Monitoring Tools | Performance Monitor.
3. Delete all default counters at the bottom of the display.
4. Click on the green + sign at the top of the display.
5. Under "Available counters," expand "SMB Client Shares."
6. Select "Data Requests/sec" which is the total number of IOPS. 
   a.  You can also select "Data Bytes/sec" if you want to see throughput and whether you are getting to the 60 MBps limit.
7. Under "Instances of selected object," choose the share(s) that you suspect are hitting the 1000 IOPS limit. 
   a.  Use Ctrl to select multiple, or choose "" to select all.
8. Click on "Add >>" and then click on OK.
   The graph will display the IOPS over time. The "Last" field displays the number of IOs in the previous second.

Comment: Thanks Sumanth for your reply. As you said to Open Performance monitor to find the IOPS used by file share. But as I am using Azure File share, where can I find Performance monitor (PerfMon.msc). Are you talking about opening Performance monitor on the VM where I have mounted the file share? Please advise.